# Heads up: HWE changes for 16.04

Tags: discussion

See the announcement:

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2016-November/000215.html

and subsequent pages:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack

TL;DR: There will be a GA kernel that will only get updates in the LTS, and then an HWE kernel, which will be rolling.

Here's the hwe tag for people interested in submitting updates/fixes to our old answers (I would start with the high traffic ones first!): https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hardware-enablement-stack

Comment: Which of these do we get if we are using the livepatch service? GA?

Comment: what does GA stand for?

Comment: @NathanOsman from the wiki page on Rolling LTS...: "For clarity, the Canonical Livepatch Service is only available and supported against the generic and lowlatency GA kernel flavours for 64-bit Intel/AMD (aka, x86_64, amd64) builds of the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial) release. HWE kernels are not supported at this time."

Comment: @muru ah, thanks.

Comment: @Mateo GA = general availability.

Comment: What does TLDR, LTS and HWE stand for? (That was a joke, but seriously what does HWE stand for)?

Comment: HardWare Enablement.  See here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack